# popup всплывает не в том месте

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, android-on-click

Если кто сталкивался, наставьте на путь истинный...
Проблема: не дружат "изменение заливки кликнутого item-а" и "появление popup над кликнутым item-ом".
По отдельности работают норм.
В тандеме что-то идет не так и popup вылазит не там где надо. 
На скриншоте: кликнул item №14, а popup вылез над item-ом №18

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код onCreateViewHolder-а:

```
private var positionSelectedItem = -1

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
    val holder = DataHolder(v)

    // вычисление высоты столбика
    calcMaxColumnHeight(holder)

    holder.itemView.statistics_item.setOnClickListener {
        val position = holder.adapterPosition

        // логика для заливки фона кликнутого столбика в оранжевый
        positionSelectedItem = position
        notifyDataSetChanged()

        val column = holder.itemView.statistics_item_column
        showPopupHint(column, list[position].second.data.toString())
    }

    return holder
}
```

Код DataHolder-а:

```
    private inner class DataHolder(item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
    private val column = item.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.item_column)
    private val tv_date = item.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_tv)

    fun bind(current: Pair<String, WorkoutJournalItem>, position: Int) {
        // bind column height
        column.layoutParams.height = calcColumnHeight(current.second)

        // bind column date
        tv_date.text = current.first

        changeColorClickedItem(column, tv_date, position)

        selectLastItem(column, tv_date, position)
    }
}

private fun changeColorClickedItem(column: CardView, tvDate: TextView, position: Int) {
    val activeColor = Color.parseColor("#f54100")                                     
    val defaultColor = Color.parseColor("#c4c4c4")                                    

    if (positionSelectedItem == position) {
        column.setCardBackgroundColor(activeColor)
        tvDate.setTextColor(activeColor)
    } else {
        column.setCardBackgroundColor(defaultColor)
        tvDate.setTextColor(defaultColor)
    }
}

fun selectLastItem(column: CardView, tvDate: TextView, position: Int) {
    val activeColor = Color.parseColor("#f54100")                                     

    if (positionSelectedItem == -1) {
        if (position == itemCount - 1) {
            column.setCardBackgroundColor(activeColor)
            tvDate.setTextColor(activeColor)
        }
    }
}
```

Код showPopupHint:

```
    private fun showPopupHint(v: View, str: String) {
    // Creation and customization popup-arrow
    val popupArrowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_statistics_popup_arrow, null, false)
    val popupArrow = PopupWindow(popupArrowView, WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
    popupArrow.animationStyle = android.R.style.Animation_Dialog
    popupArrow.isOutsideTouchable = true

    // Creation and customization popup
    val popupView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_statistics_popup_tv, null, false)
    when (typeData) {                                                                           // bind data-text
        STATISTICS_STEPS -> popupView.statistics_popup_tv.text = "$str шаг(ов)"
        STATISTICS_WATER -> popupView.statistics_popup_tv.text = "$str стакан(ов)"
        STATISTICS_WEIGHT -> popupView.statistics_popup_tv.text = "$str кг"
        STATISTICS_NUTRITION_CALORIES, STATISTICS_ACTIVITY_CALORIES -> popupView.statistics_popup_tv.text = "$str кал"
    }
    val popup = PopupWindow(popupView, WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
    popup.animationStyle = android.R.style.Animation_Dialog
    popup.isOutsideTouchable = true

    // get xOffset/yOffset popup-arrow
    val positionArrow = calcPopupPosition(popupArrowView, v)
    val xOffsetArrow = positionArrow[STATISTICS_ADAPTER_X_COORDINATE] ?: 0
    val yOffsetArrow = positionArrow[STATISTICS_ADAPTER_Y_COORDINATE] ?: 0
    val arrowHeight = positionArrow[STATISTICS_ADAPTER_VIEW_HEIGHT] ?: 0

    // get xOffset/yOffset popup
    val position = calcPopupPosition(popupView, v)
    val xOffsetPopup = position[STATISTICS_ADAPTER_X_COORDINATE] ?: 0
    val yOffsetPopup = position[STATISTICS_ADAPTER_Y_COORDINATE] ?: 0

    popupArrow.showAsDropDown(v, -(xOffsetArrow), -(yOffsetArrow))
    popup.showAsDropDown(v, -(xOffsetPopup), -(yOffsetPopup + arrowHeight))
}
```

Код calPopupPosition:

```
    private fun calcPopupPosition(popupView: View, anchorView: View): Map<String, Int> {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()

    // get measure parameters view
    val measure = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    popupView.measure(measure, measure)

    val anchorViewHeight = anchorView.height
    val anchorViewWidth = anchorView.width

    val popupHeight = popupView.measuredHeight
    val popupWidth = popupView.measuredWidth

    val xOffset = (popupWidth / 2) - (anchorViewWidth / 2)
    val yOffset = anchorViewHeight + popupHeight

    map[STATISTICS_ADAPTER_X_COORDINATE] = xOffset
    map[STATISTICS_ADAPTER_Y_COORDINATE] = yOffset
    map[STATISTICS_ADAPTER_VIEW_HEIGHT] = popupHeight
    map[STATISTICS_ADAPTER_VIEW_WIDTH] = popupWidth

    return map
}
```

Comment: Покажите код `showPopupHint()`

Comment: @Barmaley код прикрепил

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо в коде `showPopupHint()` где то добавить вызов

```
 popupWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor, dx, dy);
```

Где `anchor` это якорная вьюшка к которой будет "прикреплено" `popupWindow`- параметры `dx, dy` - это сдвижка относительно якоря

Если я правильно читаю ваш код, на роль `anchor` кажется подходит параметр `popupView: View`

Comment: но ведь я и так это делаю.                                                                  
   `popupArrow.showAsDropDown(v, -(xOffsetArrow), -(yOffsetArrow))
    popup.showAsDropDown(v, -(xOffsetPopup), -(yOffsetPopup + arrowHeight))`. Только якорной вью у меня для обоих popup-ов является сам item.